# Clean Architecture: Mapping between layers

Tags: android, kotlin, mapping, clean-architecture

I was building clean architecture, and thought that the mapping between the domain layer and the presentation layer is described by me as follows:
[Presentation layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbCXr.png)

[image: Presentation layer]

And I thought that it would be better to transfer the mapping from the presentation layer to the DI module or to a separate file that does not belong to any layer, and then I had a question, which of these two options to choose?
I ask you to help or suggest your options. I will be very grateful!

- Option 1:

  - [DI module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EgPu.png)
    [image: DI module]
  - [Inject mapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y1Ym.png)
    [image: Inject mapper]
- Option 2: [Separate file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWXKK.png)
  [image: Separate file]

Answer (score 0):

The concept of having separate data classes for each architecture layer is to have [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) between the layers. Putting your mappers in *a DI module or to a separate file that does not belong to any layer* kind of defeats its purpose.

Going by [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture#recommended-app-arch) for android, the higher layer should depend on the lower layer and not the other way around. To make this possible, the mappers between two layers should be defined in the higher layer. Take a look at [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77304158/1972597).

It should also be noted that these are mere guidelines and you are free to adapt them to your requirements.